# What is the tallest Jenga tower ever created?

Tags: jenga

Under the standard rules of Jenga, what is officially recognized as the tallest Jenga tower ever created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the the [2008 Vintage Game Collection version](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/32477/hasbro-vintage-edition-2008) of Jenga, the tallest recorded Jenga tower was made by Robert Grebler in 1985 with a tower 40 2⁄3 levels*, using an original Jenga set produced by Leslie Scott, the designer of the game.

Board Game Geek's gallery for Jenga includes a picture that nearly matches this at [40 levels tall](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/580092/jenga). The user [Romir](https://boardgamegeek.com/user/Romir) posted a picture of a tower [43 levels tall](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/946972/jenga), but it looks like they didn't follow the rule to complete a 3 block story before starting another one.**

[image: 43 Level Jenga tower]

For fun, there is a YouTube video of the [Tallest Game of Jenga Ever Assembled](https://youtu.be/zMwRuEFPWgg) at 66 inches (5.5 feet, 1.68 meters), using multiple sets.

<sup>* Presumably, the "2/3 levels" means that the Robert Grebler placed 2 out of a possible 3 blocks on the top level before the tower collapsed. In Jenga, you must place three blocks on a level before starting a new level.</sup>

<sup>** As described above, a level must have three blocks on it before starting another level. Therefore, it's not possible for both the top level and the one below it to only have one block, as shown in the picture.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For example, in this article they write https://jenga-game.com/blog/tallest-jenga-tower/
The tallest tower is 397 centimeters (slightly higher than a single-story house);
The fastest construction is 23.5 seconds from the beginning to the full tower;
The largest purchase - 125 boxes with the game were bought at a time in a retail store.